# Using Textscan to read a block

Tags: matlab, textscan

This seems like a pretty basic question and setup but I am having issues because I can't find an example that really does what I need and I find the matlab help stuff to be a bit esoteric sometimes.

File setup:

```
MiscDataAbove

MyTargetData_0
{
Position     1.1 2.2 3.3;
Velocity     001;
Altitude     001;
StartTime    001;
StopTime     001;
}

MiscDataBelow
```

I want my matlab code to find the "MyTargetData_0" line, and read all of the data below starting with "{" and ending with "}" into a variable with the following format:

```
Position | 1.1 | 2.2 | 3.3
Velocity | 001
etc..
etc..
```

Any help would be fantastic. Thanks all!

Comment: What have you tried? You will likely not find a directo MATLAB solution to your problem, you will need to write it yourself. Also what do you mean put it in a variable with that format? in a string? in a table?

Comment: I have been trying various fread textscan regexp things for a few hours now. It would be too exhaustive to transfer it here and the system I am using is separate from the system I am able to post things on.

I would like it to be in a table if possible.

Comment: Apologies, but I fully disagree with your assessment of the situation. You come here asking for help, therefore its your job to do the maximal effort to get this thing solved, as it is your problem and no one elses. We are not going to just write it for you. What we can do is, if you show a [mcve], help you overcome the problems that we might see in your code. For you to show the effort you made and why/how it didn't work the minimum that we can expect when you are asking for free help.

Comment: I just need to know where to start. I don't need you to do it for me.

The all of the work is based on a classified computing asset. I can't just go in there and copy down what i've been trying.

Comment: Then you should start with `fread` and `textscan` as you did. Hopefully that answers your question. Otherwise, add a [mcve]. Not your codebase. Just a [mcve]